# How to adjust read_excel so that thousand seperator is not changed to decimal point?

Tags: r

Currently, I use the following code to store Excel files (which are stored in a folder on my PC) in a list.

```
decrease_names <- list.files("4_large_decreases",pattern = ".xlsx",full.names = T)
decrease_list <- sapply(decrease_names,read_excel,simplify = F)
```

After that, I combine the dataframes into one object by using the following code.

```
decrease <- decrease_list %>% 
  keep(function(x) nrow(x) > 0) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

The problem I have is that the Excel files that are stored in the folder contain decimal points (points ".") as well as thousand separators (commas ","). I think R (and read_excel() in particular) convert the thousand separators into decimal points, which results in incorrect data.

Although I know that I can remove the thousand separators in Excel first, this would result in a lot of manual work and hence I am interested in a solution that recognises the thousand separator and keeps it intact (or removes it, the goal is to keep the nature of the data correct).

EDIT: as @dario suggested I add a snippet of a tibble that is stored in `decrease_list` after I run the code. The snippet looks like this:

```
Raised   Avg. change
526.000  2.04
186.000  3.24
...
```

In the column raised the "." used to be a "," but has become a ".". The "." in Avg. change was a "." already.

Comment: Are you sure the values in the excel are not "numbers stored as text" or just plain text?

Comment: My first guess would be to read the data via `readxl::read_excel()` and specify the `col_type` as character. Then you could simply replace the ',' by using `gsub()` and convert to numeric with `as.numeric()`.

Comment: I think you need to post some sample of how the data in question looks after the import. Then we can suggest appropriate ways to deal with it in R (don't worry, you most likely won't have to manually fix the excel files)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @tacoman I have tried to run the following code:
```price_names <- list.files("1_summary_price",pattern = ".xlsx",full.names = T)

price_list <- sapply(price_names,read_excel(col_types = "text"),simplify = F)```
but this produces the following error:
```Error in check_file(path) : argument "path" is missing, with no default```
while this is not produced when ```(col_types = "text")``` is not mentioned.

Comment: It is required to specify the col_type for each column you read.

Comment: @tacoman ```price_list <- sapply(price_names,read_excel(col_types = c("text","text","text","text","text","text","text","text","text","text")),simplify = F)``` produces the same error. Do you have an other idea what goes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that each excel file contains data in the same format, then we can apply the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

decrease_names <- list.files("4_large_decreases",pattern = ".xlsx",full.names = T)

# 10 columns as written in your comment
decrease <- sapply(decrease_names, readxl::read_excel, col_types = rep("text", 10L), simplify = F)

# Not tested
decrease <- decrease_list %>% 
  keep(function(x) nrow(x) > 0) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.character), ~ as.numeric(gsub("\\,", "", .x))))
```

Comment: Hi @Tacoman, thanks for your reply :-)

Unfortunately, I have not managed to solve the problem. The `sapply` function now works and reads in the columns as text. When I subsequently try to remove the separators (which are still decimal points) it produces a strange result. Part of a column of the tibble (text form): 
`[1] "22.902000000000001" "23.108000000000001"` 
Meanwhile, the following code:
`gsub(".", "", column)` 
gives 
`[1] "" ""` 
The following code: 
`gsub(".", ",", column)`
 gives `[1] ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,," ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"`
Do you know what to do?

Comment: Got the problem. I did not think about that, sorry. You have to escape the `"\\."`. Same applies for `"\\,"` I upgraded my answer.

Comment: Hey @tacoman, thanks for your reply! Escaping the character was indeed necessary in the `gsub` command. I accepted your answer!